# Get value indices from dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, indices

I have an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict([('r', 1), ('s', 5), ('a', 3), ('n', 7), ('y', 2)])
```

I'd like to get indices of dictionary values according to values range. For example, indices of dictionary `d` should be array (or `np.array`), like following:

```
indices
array([ 0, 3, 2, 4, 1 ], dtype=int64)
```

index `4` is a biggest value in dictionary, index `0` is smallest value

I tried :

```
indices = np.argsort(d.values)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to implement this:

```
>>> values = d.values()
>>> sorted_values = sorted(values)
>>> [sorted_values.index(item) for item in values]
[0, 3, 2, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is `O(n^2)`, so I've posted a (theoretically) more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tried with argsort:

```
np.argsort(d.values()).argsort()
Out[50]: array([0, 3, 2, 4, 1], dtype=int64)
```

So argsort does not actually return their orders but it returns the indices that would sort that array. Calling argsort on that result does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is nice and simple but is `O(n^2)` as each `.index` is `O(n)`. You can precompute the indices in a dictionary so that the index lookups are `O(1)`, making the whole thing `O(nlogn)` as the sort is the most expensive part. If `d` is large enough this will be a *very* important difference.

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> indices = dict(izip(sorted_values, xrange(len(d))))
>>> indices
{1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 2, 5: 3, 7: 4}
>>> [indices[v] for v in d.itervalues()]
[0, 3, 2, 4, 1]
```

Here I've used `xrange` instead of `range`, `izip` instead of `zip`, and `itervalues` instead of `values` for memory efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I forgot to put `()` after values , so I used `indices = np.argsort(d.values())`

Comment: Yes but np.argsort alone does not return the result you want. It returns `array([0, 4, 2, 1, 3], dtype=int64)`.